# free-jqGrid change shrinkToFit dynamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free-jqGrid and I'd like to set the shrinkToFit option dynamically depending on the size of the window.
Is there a way to do it?
and another question while I'm a it,
What is the event, like  onSelectRow: function (){}, for the click on the inline edit button?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you call the method `setGridWidth` explicitly, then you can use the last parameter (`shrink`) *independent from the value of `shrinkToFit`*. It should solve your problem.